# Customize spring-data-jpa base repository in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to customize my base repository in my spring-boot application. It looks like:

Base Interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {
    // ... customized methods ...
}
```

Base Implementation:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {
    // constructor
    public MyRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    // ... customized methods implementations ...
}
```

As you can see, I want to use Querydsl.
In spring-data-jpa, the only class I can find that implements the `JpaRepository` and `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` interfaces at the same time is only `QuerydslJpaRepository`, but it is `@Deprecated`.
If my base repository (`MyRepositoryImpl.class`) cannot be inherited from `QuerydslJpaRepository`, do I have any other options?

---

Another question:
If I don't care about @Deprecated, can I configure @EnableJpaRepositories directly in the Spring-Boot environment?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)
public class PersistenceConfig {
    // ...
}
```

I am worried that this will destroy many of the built-in infrastructure of Spring-Boot, and I need to reconfigure them by myself (such as `transactionManager` or other beans).
Whether spring-boot provides a *customizer* allows me to configure only the attribute value without affecting all other auto-configuration behaviors.

Comment: You have no other options. QueryDSL is considered obsolete (it isn't maintained anymore) and support will be removed in a later Spring Data JPA version. So if you want to use QueryDSL this is your only option (and you will limit your upgrade possibilities as well).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it the official Spring documentation that the support for Querydsl is about to be dropped? On Github, the Querydsl project is constantly being updated. It's not like a project to be abandoned. In addition to Querydsl, are there any equivalent projects that can be well supported by spring-data-jpa?

Comment: My bad, it isn't Spring Data JPA that is deprecating the support. You should use a different class for the DSL support (see the deprecated note in the javadoc for the class you are using). Regarding your other question that is the way you should specify the repository base class and it will not limit you in any other way.

Comment: But the class `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` only implements the interface `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`, and does not implement the interface `JpaRepository`. My base repository class cannot be directly inherited from `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor`. According to the definition of the `MyRepository` interface, the implementation class I selected must contain the implementation of the `JpaRepository<T, ID>` interface and the implementation of the `QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T>` interface.

Comment: The parts have been split so you probably need another way to override he querydsl parts. Also do you really need to replace the base repository?